# Initializing new class objects from Console.Readline() and adding them into list

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, class, oop

I've encountered one problem that I couldn't solve since 3 days. I will really appreciate any advice.

I would like user to initialize an object by typing all of the properties referred in the constructor via Console.Readline() and then that object should be stored in the list of objects.

```
namespace ExampleA {

    public class ExampleClass 
    {

        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int Age {get; set;}

        public Example(string name, int age) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age; 
        }
    }

    class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {

        List<ExampleClass> example_list = new List<ExampleClass>();

        example_list.Add(new ExampleClass
        {
          name = Console.Readline();
          age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline());
        }
    }
```

I receive after trying to compile everytime an error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' of 'ExampleClass.Example(string, int)'.

Comment: Understanding exception messages belongs to basic programming skills. You shouldn't have to ask on Stack Overflow what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

One error, as pointed out by @Tim Schmelter, is that you typed the wrong names for properties: they should be `Name` and `Age`. You should write `Console.ReadLine()` and not `Console.Readline()`.

Also, you declared a constructor that requires name and age as parameters, it's the only constructor for the object so you must use it when creating an instance with the syntax `new ExampleClass(name, age) { //setting other properties }` **OR** provide an empty constructor. Here's an example:

```
public class ExampleClass
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }


    public ExampleClass(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

}

public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<ExampleClass> example_list = new List<ExampleClass>();

        example_list.Add(new ExampleClass(Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()))
        {
            Surname = Console.ReadLine()
        });

        //The following does not compile
        example_list.Add(new ExampleClass
        {
            Surname = Console.ReadLine()
        });

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that you do not use the constructor defined for the class `ExampleClass`. Note that the syntax `new ExampleClass { ... }` uses the default class constructor with no parameters. In your case the default constructor has been hidden. You need to define a new constructor with no parameters (`public ExampleClass()`) or to use the existing one:

Using the defined constructor:

```
 example_list.Add(new ExampleClass
        (
          Name: Console.Readline(),
          Age: Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline())
        ));
```

Object Initializer Syntax:

```
 public class ExampleClass 
    {

        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int Age {get; set;}

        public Example(string name, int age) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age; 
        }
        // constructor with no parameters will let you
        // use the Object Initializer Syntax without specifying 
        // the constructor explicitly
        public Example() {}
    }
```

after defining a 'default' constructor the following should work fine:

```
 example_list.Add(new ExampleClass
            {
              name = Console.Readline();
              age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see other issues in your code. let's suppose the user enters the wrong value for age? then your program will crash. so you have to either keep on trying or catch the error.

```
List<ExampleClass> example_list = new List<ExampleClass>();
string Name = Console.ReadLine();
int Age;

while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Age) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter valid age");
}

ExampleClass obj = new ExampleClass(Name, Age);
example_list.Add(obj);
```

You can enhance this solution by proving relevant checks like the age limit, it should be from 0 to 100 or so..... you can do handle this in `set` property or like the way I have added check.